# Is there a way to use some kind of cache for results of the most often used queries in Spark?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, bigdata

Is there a way to use some kind of cache for results of the most often used queries in Spark (or by using other Hadoop libraries)?

Comment: See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html#caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean cache, then you can call that exact method (`cache`) on your returned `RDD`.